# Combine 2 HTML log files in one HTML log files in Coded UI

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

I am working on Coded UI and I am generating an HTML log file. But, I have 2 test cases and I don't want to generate 2 log file for these 2 test cases.

So Is there any way we can generate single log file for 2 test case?

And also I want to know how we will generate the HTML Log file in OrderTest?